# How to distinguish between null and '0' in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to determine whether a value saved using the `ng-model` is simply null or if a 0 was typed, in Angular.JS?

Basically, I am trying to use resolve in my route to send the user back to `#/page-1`, if they try to go to `#/page-2` and the `vm.data.foo` was not completed. Like in the case of a browser page refresh, which resets the temporary data.

The problem I have run into though, is that if the user types in a "0", it is being treated the same as a null value by Angular.JS. Is there anyway to make a distinction between the two using an `if` statement?

In my `#/page-1` view:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="vm.Data.foo" />
```

My Route for `#/page-2`:

```
        $routeProvider.when("/page-2", {
            controller: "page2Controller",
            controllerAs: "vm",
            templateUrl: "/content/templates/page2View.html",
            resolve: {
                validate: function ($location, Data) {
                    // if Data.foo was not entered, send back to page-1
                    if (!Data.foo && Data.foo != 0) {
                        $location.path('/page-1');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

This was one of my attempts, but it does not work. On a browser refresh, it does not redirect back to page-1 when `Data.foo` is null, because it is seen the same as 0.

Any ideas for a work around?

---

**Solution** (thanks to Chet's answer):

```
    $routeProvider.when("/page-2", {
        controller: "page2Controller",
        controllerAs: "vm",
        templateUrl: "/content/templates/page2View.html",
        resolve: {
            validate: function ($location, Data) {
                // if Data.foo was not entered, send back to page-1
                if (Data.foo === '') {
                    $location.path('/page-1');
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that it is treating null as 0, it is treating both 0 and null as false. `!(null) == true` as is `!(0) == true`. You want something more like:

```
if (Data.foo === null) {
```

Comment: Thank you! The triple equal sign worked. I just had to change it to: `if (Data.foo === '') { }`. I will have to lookup how `===` is different from simply `==`.

Comment: === does not do type coercion. For example, `0 == '0'` is true, but `0 === '0'` is not.

Comment: `==` will convert the operands to the same type first, `===` does not convert and will only be true if both are of the same type. `0 == false; // true` but `0 === false; // false`

Answer (score 2):

Use simply :

```
if(Data.foo == null){}
```

In javascript, `null`, `0` and empty strings are processed as `false` when used in `if` statement as a statement